# How make a fixed content scrollable in Bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap-4

[Bootstrap, keep div fixed after scrolling to it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28340054/bootstrap-keep-div-fixed-after-scrolling-to-it)

I found the way to fix the position but my content is too much and overflowed
How to make the content scrollable in the fixed position?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just set a maximum height <= 100vh to keep the entire element within view. Then set overflow to scroll or auto. Auto adds scrollbars only when necessary.

```
max-height: 90vh;
overflow: auto;
```

See my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vzyx758n/)