# Fixed position div on top vertical space

Tags: html, css, fixed

My situation is that I have fixed position div with percented height at the bottom of page that is on top of it(see picture). The issue is that when I scroll page to the end, some of its content is hidden beneath this div. I think I should add empty element at the bottom of page, but what is the best way to do it? [image]

Comment: Have you seen this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20100461/jquery-position-div-fixed-at-top-on-scroll

Comment: To dynamically do that you will need to use `javascript`. Are you using `javascript` or `jquery`?

Comment: May be you need to check if the container of scroll content and the fixed div is overlapped. add some border to the div to check.

Comment: try adding margin-bottom for body. i.e. body{ margin-bottom: height of fixed div ; }?

Comment: I can't use javascript, it's a third-party page I need to apply styles to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A nice solution could be to change the height of the fixed div to be expressed in `vh` not in `%` ([see](http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/vm-vh-units)), for example:

```
div.fixed-at-bottom { height: 20vh; .... }
```

and then set a `margin-bottom` to your contents div with the same value (or a little more to get more space):

```
div.content { margin-bottom: 22vh; .... }
```

I created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h465u3cz/1/) to present that.

Comment: Indeed, CSS 3 is awesome :)