# Fix table header

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll, css-position

I have a table with much rows and columns. The table header needs to be fixed on the browser window when scrolling vertical. I have done that by adding a style `position: fixed;` to the table head when it reaches the top of the browser window.

But when I scroll horizontally the table header is not scrolling in the way as I applied the fixed position.

How can I make the table header scroll horizontally (also).

**Javascript:**

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var spec_lot_dash_sticky = $('.spec_dash_thead'),
        spec_lot_dash_scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (spec_lot_dash_scroll >= ($("#table_id").offset().top)) {
        spec_lot_dash_sticky.addClass('fixed')
        $(".fixed").css("top", spec_lot_dash_thead_scroll_top)
    } else {
        spec_lot_dash_sticky.removeClass('fixed');
    }

});
```

[jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/ssp/myn73u1s/2/)
First scroll the vertical bar and then scroll horizontall scroll bar. The table header is not scrolling.

Comment: Can you provide working jsfiddle with your issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery position DIV fixed at top on scroll](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20100461/jquery-position-div-fixed-at-top-on-scroll)

Comment: Pete.. the link  you provided is same as i done. I have fixed my header on top but my issue is when i scroll horizontal scrollbar of window the header is not scrolling along with data in tbody

Comment: @user2083041 This question may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3303173/position-element-fixed-vertically-absolute-horizontally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also set its horizontal position at scroll based on the table position:

```
spec_lot_dash_sticky.css('left', $("#filter_table").offset().left - $(window).scrollLeft());
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/myn73u1s/3/).

Comment: Thank you so much Mr. Miraco.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need any `jQuery`, to achieve the table you describe.

It's possible to reproduce a fixed `<thead>` and a vertically scrolling `<tbody>`, simply by using `CSS`:

```css
.fixed{position:fixed}

#filter_table thead, #filter_table tbody {
display: block;
position: relative;
}

#filter_table th, #filter_table td {
width: 120px;
text-align: center;
}

#filter_table tbody {
height: 200px;
overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<table id="filter_table" style="margin-top:5%">

<thead class="spec_dash_thead" style="background-color:blue">
<tr>
<th>header1</th>
<th>header2</th>
<th>header3</th>
<th>header4</th>
<th>header5</th>
<th>header6</th>
</tr>
</thead>
      
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>data1</td>
<td>data2</td>
<td>data3</td>
<td>data4</td>
<td>data5</td>
<td>data6</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>data1</td>
<td>data2</td>
<td>data3</td>
<td>data4</td>
<td>data5</td>
<td>data6</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>data1</td>
<td>data2</td>
<td>data3</td>
<td>data4</td>
<td>data5</td>
<td>data6</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>data1</td>
<td>data2</td>
<td>data3</td>
<td>data4</td>
<td>data5</td>
<td>data6</td>
</tr> <tr>
<td>data1</td>
<td>data2</td>
<td>data3</td>
<td>data4</td>
<td>data5</td>
<td>data6</td>
</tr> <tr>
<td>data1</td>
<td>data2</td>
<td>data3</td>
<td>data4</td>
<td>data5</td>
<td>data6</td>
</tr> <tr>
<td>data1</td>
<td>data2</td>
<td>data3</td>
<td>data4</td>
<td>data5</td>
<td>data6</td>
</tr> <tr>
<td>data1</td>
<td>data2</td>
<td>data3</td>
<td>data4</td>
<td>data5</td>
<td>data6</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>data1</td>
<td>data2</td>
<td>data3</td>
<td>data4</td>
<td>data5</td>
<td>data6</td>
</tr> <tr>
<td>data1</td>
<td>data2</td>
<td>data3</td>
<td>data4</td>
<td>data5</td>
<td>data6</td>
</tr> <tr>
<td>data1</td>
<td>data2</td>
<td>data3</td>
<td>data4</td>
<td>data5</td>
<td>data6</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>data1</td>
<td>data2</td>
<td>data3</td>
<td>data4</td>
<td>data5</td>
<td>data6</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>data1</td>
<td>data2</td>
<td>data3</td>
<td>data4</td>
<td>data5</td>
<td>data6</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>data1</td>
<td>data2</td>
<td>data3</td>
<td>data4</td>
<td>data5</td>
<td>data6</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>data1</td>
<td>data2</td>
<td>data3</td>
<td>data4</td>
<td>data5</td>
<td>data6</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>data1</td>
<td>data2</td>
<td>data3</td>
<td>data4</td>
<td>data5</td>
<td>data6</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>data1</td>
<td>data2</td>
<td>data3</td>
<td>data4</td>
<td>data5</td>
<td>data6</td>
</tr>
</tbody>

</table>
```

Comment: I dont need a scroll bar for tbody.  I need to use browser scroll bar only and on horizontal scroll bar i need to scroll thead also