# Floating header row

Tags: html, css, fixed-header-tables

I've been trying to freeze my top row but I end up with just "Test3" header floating about.
I used `position: fixed;` under `table th {}`, but no luck.
Any suggestions?

```css
html body {
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
#header {
  background: #0066a1;
  color: #ffffff;
  width: 100%
}
#headerTop {
  padding: 10px;
}
.logo1 {
  float: left;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 0 7px 0 0;
}
.logo2 {
  float: left;
  font-size: 25px;
}
.logo3 {
  float: right;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: right;
}
.headerRow1 {
  background: #66a3c7;
  height: 10px;
}
.serverRow {
  background: #000000;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 32px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.sectionRow {
  background: #0066a1;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 1px 5px!important;
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 15px!important;
}
table {
  background: #eaebec;
  border: #cccccc 1px solid;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
table th {
  background: #ededed;
  border-top: 1px solid #fafafa;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
  border-left: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
  padding: 2px 2px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  position: fixed
}
table tr {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 13px;
}
table td {
  background: #fafafa;
  border-top: 1px solid #ffffff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
  border-left: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
  padding: 2px 2px;
  font-size: 11px;
}
table td:first-child {
  text-align: left;
}
table tr:last-child td {
  border-bottom: 0;
}
table tr:hover td {
  background: #f2f2f2;
}
table tr:hover td.sectionRow {
  background: #0066a1;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div id="headerTop">
    <div class="logo1"></div>
    <div class="logo2">Logo 1</div>
    <div class="logo3">
      <br/>date and time</div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
  </div>
  <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
<div class="headerRow1"></div>
<div class="serverRow">Header</div>
<div class="headerRow1"></div>
<table>
  <colgroup>
    <col/>
    <col/>
    <col/>
    <col/>
    <col/>
    <col/>
    <col/>
    <col/>
    <col/>
    <col/>
    <col/>
    <col/>
    <col/>
    <col/>
    <col/>
  </colgroup>
  <tr>
    <th>test1</th>
    <th>test2</th>
    <th>test3</th>
    <th>test3</th>
    <th>test3</th>
    <th>test3</th>
    <th>test3</th>
    <th>test3</th>
    <th>test3</th>
    <th>test3</th>
    <th>test3</th>
    <th>test3</th>
    <th>test3</th>
    <th>test3</th>
    <th>test3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <tddata17</td>
      <td style="background:tomato;">data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td style="background:#00ff00;">data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <tddata17</td>
      <td style="background:tomato;">data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td style="background:#00ff00;">data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <tddata17</td>
      <td style="background:tomato;">data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td style="background:#00ff00;">data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <tddata17</td>
      <td style="background:tomato;">data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td style="background:#00ff00;">data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <tddata17</td>
      <td style="background:tomato;">data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td style="background:#00ff00;">data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <tddata17</td>
      <td style="background:tomato;">data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td style="background:#00ff00;">data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <tddata17</td>
      <td style="background:tomato;">data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td style="background:#00ff00;">data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <tddata17</td>
      <td style="background:tomato;">data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td style="background:#00ff00;">data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <tddata17</td>
      <td style="background:tomato;">data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td style="background:#00ff00;">data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <tddata17</td>
      <td style="background:tomato;">data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td style="background:#00ff00;">data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <tddata17</td>
      <td style="background:tomato;">data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td style="background:#00ff00;">data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <tddata17</td>
      <td style="background:tomato;">data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td style="background:#00ff00;">data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <tddata17</td>
      <td style="background:tomato;">data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td style="background:#00ff00;">data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <tddata17</td>
      <td style="background:tomato;">data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td style="background:#00ff00;">data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <tddata17</td>
      <td style="background:tomato;">data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td style="background:#00ff00;">data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <tddata17</td>
      <td style="background:tomato;">data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td style="background:#00ff00;">data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <tddata17</td>
      <td style="background:tomato;">data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td style="background:#00ff00;">data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <tddata17</td>
      <td style="background:tomato;">data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td style="background:#00ff00;">data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <tddata17</td>
      <td style="background:tomato;">data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td style="background:#00ff00;">data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <tddata17</td>
      <td style="background:tomato;">data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td style="background:#00ff00;">data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <tddata17</td>
      <td style="background:tomato;">data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td style="background:#00ff00;">data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <tddata17</td>
      <td style="background:tomato;">data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td style="background:#00ff00;">data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <tddata17</td>
      <td style="background:tomato;">data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td style="background:#00ff00;">data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <tddata17</td>
      <td style="background:tomato;">data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td style="background:#00ff00;">data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <tddata17</td>
      <td style="background:tomato;">data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td style="background:#00ff00;">data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <tddata17</td>
      <td style="background:tomato;">data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td style="background:#00ff00;">data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <tddata17</td>
      <td style="background:tomato;">data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td style="background:#00ff00;">data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <tddata17</td>
      <td style="background:tomato;">data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td style="background:#00ff00;">data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <tddata17</td>
      <td style="background:tomato;">data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td style="background:#00ff00;">data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <tddata17</td>
      <td style="background:tomato;">data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td style="background:#00ff00;">data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <tddata17</td>
      <td style="background:tomato;">data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td style="background:#00ff00;">data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <tddata17</td>
      <td style="background:tomato;">data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td style="background:#00ff00;">data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <tddata17</td>
      <td style="background:tomato;">data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td style="background:#00ff00;">data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <tddata17</td>
      <td style="background:tomato;">data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td style="background:#00ff00;">data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <tddata17</td>
      <td style="background:tomato;">data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td style="background:#00ff00;">data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <tddata17</td>
      <td style="background:tomato;">data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td style="background:#00ff00;">data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <tddata17</td>
      <td style="background:tomato;">data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td style="background:#00ff00;">data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <tddata17</td>
      <td style="background:tomato;">data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td style="background:#00ff00;">data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <tddata17</td>
      <td style="background:tomato;">data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td style="background:#00ff00;">data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <tddata17</td>
      <td style="background:tomato;">data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td style="background:#00ff00;">data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <tddata17</td>
      <td style="background:tomato;">data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td style="background:#00ff00;">data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <tddata17</td>
      <td style="background:tomato;">data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td style="background:#00ff00;">data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <tddata17</td>
      <td style="background:tomato;">data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td style="background:#00ff00;">data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <tddata17</td>
      <td style="background:tomato;">data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td style="background:#00ff00;">data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <tddata17</td>
      <td style="background:tomato;">data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td style="background:#00ff00;">data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <tddata17</td>
      <td style="background:tomato;">data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td style="background:#00ff00;">data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <tddata17</td>
      <td style="background:tomato;">data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td style="background:#00ff00;">data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <tddata17</td>
      <td style="background:tomato;">data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td style="background:#00ff00;">data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <tddata17</td>
      <td style="background:tomato;">data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td style="background:#00ff00;">data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <tddata17</td>
      <td style="background:tomato;">data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td style="background:#00ff00;">data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <tddata17</td>
      <td style="background:tomato;">data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td style="background:#00ff00;">data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <tddata17</td>
      <td style="background:tomato;">data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td style="background:#00ff00;">data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <tddata17</td>
      <td style="background:tomato;">data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td style="background:#00ff00;">data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <tddata17</td>
      <td style="background:tomato;">data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td style="background:#00ff00;">data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <tddata17</td>
      <td style="background:tomato;">data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td style="background:#00ff00;">data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <tddata17</td>
      <td style="background:tomato;">data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td style="background:#00ff00;">data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <tddata17</td>
      <td style="background:tomato;">data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td style="background:#00ff00;">data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
    <tddata17</td>
      <td style="background:tomato;">data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td style="background:#00ff00;">data</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

[View on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/manishvaja1/mzrskme2/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML table with fixed headers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/673153/html-table-with-fixed-headers) ... Use search force, Luke.

Comment: which part do you want to be fixed? the black row with text 'header'?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/673153/html-table-with-fixed-headers

Answer (score 0):

I don't sure about your question, but seems that you want to create a header [fixed with scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20100461/jquery-position-div-fixed-at-top-on-scroll) , other option is wrap all your content to be fixed on one div and apply for all of that.

Other example of table with header fixed:  `codepen.io/tjvantoll/pen/JEKIu`

Answer (score 0):

All of your `<th>` tags that you fixed are stacked on top of each other.  Apply fixed to the `<tr>` that you want fixed instead.

Also if the top `<tr>` that you want fixed is the headers to the columns they should be in a `<thead>`. Then your other `<tr>`s should be in a `<tbody>`. This will also allow you to target the  that you want to fix in your CSS with `thead tr`.

Or even better, just fix the entire `<thead>` with `thead {position: fixed}`